# my application stopped working with xulrunner 10.0.4

Tags: centos, xulrunner, centos6

When I upgraded to `centos 6` and `xulrunner 10.0.4`, my app stopped working. Xulrunner just hangs.

My directory structure:

```
.
|-- application.ini
|-- chrome
|   |-- chrome.manifest
|   `-- content
|       |-- main.xul
|       `-- main.xul.tpl.org
|-- defaults
|   `-- preferences
|       `-- prefs.js
```

Comment: Since we have no idea what's in these files, it's sort of hard to debug your app.

Comment: Yes, indeed. If you send me your app, I can check. Please send the code to ales.kotnik@gmail.com.

Comment: thanx. i will send you the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [example application](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Getting_started_with_XULRunner) from developer.mozilla.org, your application is missing the `chrome.manifest` as a sibling file of `application.ini` with the content:

```
manifest chrome/chrome.manifest
```

The funny thing is it works on xulrunner 12.0 but not on 10.0. Just add the file and your application should work.